# trouble with update / SQLite don't nothing

Tags: java, sqlite

My problem is simple. The code works for **add** and **delete** but if I **edit** it, only update price (real in db), the category (integer in db) and name remains the same. And if I edit name, price and category, it does nothing!

It's weird why in the console nothing is printed.

---

```
public void actualizarArticulo(Articulo art) {
    Conexion con = new Conexion();
    try {
        con.conectar();
        //Esta consulta es para obtener y guardar el numero de id de la categoria del art
        int idCat=0;
        PreparedStatement st = con.getConnection().prepareStatement("select * from categorias where nombreCat=(?);");
        st.setString(1, art.getCategoria());
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()){
            idCat=rs.getInt("idCat");
        }
        //Esta consulta es para actualizar el art
        System.out.println(art.getNombre());
        st= con.getConnection().prepareStatement("Update articulos set nombreArt=?,precioArt=?,categoriaArt=? where idArt=?;");
        st.setString(1, art.getNombre());
        st.setFloat(2, art.getPrecio());
        st.setInt(3, idCat);
        st.setInt(4, art.getId());
        st.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se actualizo ");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }finally {
        con.cerrar();
    }
}
```

---

The rest of my program is in [github](https://github.com/srfrankie/Vivero).

Comment: Are you getting category name using `getCategoria()` function in `SELECT` statement? Did you check after `SELECT` statement whether `idCat` is populated with proper value or not?

Comment: i check, the variables are sending are right , but doesn't update